# Angular material dashboard - Unique content with ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngfor

I am in the process of using the Angular Material Dashboard schematic.  I have it working as expected and everything is in place.  I suppose my question is more about the ngFor directive that is used to populate the dashboard with Material Cards.

The template uses ngFor to place a few cards on the page giving it the dashboard feel.  This seems like a nice easy approach.  However, in practice, how would you populate the cards individually with content.  For example, say I wanted to have a pie chart in one, a line graph in another and maybe some text in the 3rd.  How do you place unique content when using an ngFor?  Is it possible?  Or is ngFor used in the dashboard schematic in this instance just as a quick example?

I guess what I'm really struggling to understand is how to leverage Angular to minimize code?  As I understand it right now, it seems like each card, when put in to practice would need it's own component, it's own template etc.  Certainly I could reuse a service across components to fetch the required data from the API, but will I have to create unique components for each card?

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: I was trying to avoid posting any code as it is more of a theoretical question but... since you asked :).  I currently have what I want, (targeting unique cards) by using slice on the array.  However this seems insane to do as it will require a unique chunk of code for each card, thus rendering ngFor useless.  Does that make sense?  In the dashboard component I essentially have now, two card elements where previously there was an ngFor to iterate over a cards list living in the component.ts file.

Comment: It depends on your needs. From what you are saying, it seems to me that each card should be an individual component with its own logic and visual contents

Comment: You could potentially group some cards together if they belong to a common logical group, but splitting your app in modular chunks is usually a good idea

Comment: So in my compnent.ts file I have something like cards = [ { title: 'Store 1', cols: 2, rows: 1 }, { title: 'Store 2', cols: 2, rows: 1} etc.  I can use ngFor fine to populate the cards with the title, however when it's time to place unique content or elements in the cards (such as a chart or graph) how can I do that while using ngFor?  It seems I will have to create a unique card element(s) for each item in the array and then populate the card-content individually.

Comment: @bugs - Okay, this is what I assumed I would need to do but I wasn't certain because that seems like an insane amount of code and components when the user could have up to 20-30 cards to chose from on the dashboard.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing an obvious trick that angular provides as I am still learning angular.